# Is there a conda-develop directive for environment.yml?

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to configure `environment.yml` for setting up project environments to be as automated as possible. Right now, it seems like the best way to deploy a development environment is by using a yaml file and then calling `conda develop`:

```
conda env create --file environment.yml
conda develop .
```

Is there a proper way to embed the develop step within the initial yaml? (e.g. I can add a  `- pip:\n   - --editable .` block in `dependencies:` to install in development mode using `pip`.)